# Can we add a friend class based on template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I wonder whether the below tricky situation is possible:

Suppose I have a template class `template <typename DTYPE> class A{};`, where `DTYPE` is supposed to be one of `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, etc. I want to add a friend class to `A`, but this friend class differs for each `DTYPE` alternative. Further, suppose the friend classes for different `DTYPE` values are **not** instantiations of another template class, but independent classes.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What about specializing your template?

Comment: Could you use a `template <typename T> class Friend;`, and then have specialisations for each `Friend<...>` you wish to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add template "proxy" class `FriendOfA` and specialize it for whatever type you need:

```
// actual friends
class FriendUint8 {};
class FriendUint16 {};

template<typename T> struct FriendOfA;

template<>
struct FriendOfA<uint8_t> {
    typedef FriendUint8 type;
};

template<>
struct FriendOfA<uint16_t> {
    typedef FriendUint16 type;
};

// optional helper
template <typename T>
using FriendOfA_t = typename FriendOfA<T>::type;

template<class T>
class A {
    friend typename FriendOfA<T>::type;
    // or simply
    friend FriendOfA_t<T>;
};
```

Comment: This answer seems to be elegant and have minimal coding effort. I will  accept this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for something like that:

```
#include <iostream>

struct BaseFriend 
{
    template <typename T>
    void boo(const T& t) { t.foo(); }   
};

struct BaseFriendProxy
{
    template <typename T>
    void boo(const T& t) { std::cout << "Proxy: "; t.foo(); }   
};

template <typename TType> 
struct Friend ;

template <>
struct Friend<int> {
    using T = BaseFriend;
};

template <>
struct Friend<char> {
    using T = BaseFriendProxy;
};

template <typename DTYPE> 
class A
{
private:
    friend typename Friend<DTYPE>::T;

    void foo() const 
    { std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl; }    
};

int main()
{
   A<int> a;
   BaseFriend bf1;
   bf1.boo(a);

   A<char> b;
   BaseFriendProxy bf2;
   bf2.boo(b);

   return 0;
}
```

But this will work only with C++11: you can't combine `friend class ...` with `typename X::Y` in C++03

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, specialize your template and add whatever friend class you want:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base {
 public:
    virtual int getValue() = 0;
};

class friend1 {
    public:
    base* ptr;

    int getValue() {
        return ptr->getValue();
    }
};

class friend2 {
    public:
    base* ptr;

    int getValue() {
        return ptr->getValue();
    }
};

template <typename DTYPE> class A :  public base{
    public:

    A() { data = 42; }

    // No friends

    private:
    int data;

    int getValue() {
        return data;
    }
};

template <> class A<char> :  public base{
    public:

    A() { data = 44; }

    friend class friend1;

    private:
    int data;

    int getValue() {
        return data;
    }
};

template <> class A<bool> :  public base{
    public:

    A() { data = 45; }

    friend class friend2;

    private:
    int data;

    int getValue() {
        return data;
    }
};


int main()
{
    A<char> obj1;
    friend1 friend_of_obj1;
    friend_of_obj1.ptr = &obj1;
    cout << friend_of_obj1.getValue() << endl;

    A<bool> obj2;
    friend2 friend_of_obj2;
    friend_of_obj2.ptr = &obj2;
    cout << friend_of_obj2.getValue();

}
```

http://ideone.com/hM9x0y

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a friend can be based on a template. Such as;

```
template <typename DTYPE>
struct Friend;

template <class DTYPE>
class A {
    friend struct Friend<DTYPE>;
};
```

For each type `DTYPE` for the class `A` you wish to support (different by implementation) you can specialise `Friend`, such as;

```
template<>
struct Friend<uint8_t> {
    // ...
};
```

A basic working sample:

```
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Friend;

template <class T>
class A {
    friend struct Friend<T>;

    int i = 0;    
};

template<>
struct Friend<uint8_t> {
    void method() {
        A<uint8_t> a;
        a.i = 8;
    }
};

template<>
struct Friend<uint16_t> {
    void method() {
        A<uint16_t> a;
        //A<uint8_t> b; // fails to compile
        a.i = 16;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<uint8_t> a;
    Friend<uint8_t> f;
    f.method();
}
```